# Airflow Python operator passing parameters

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to write a Python operator in an airflow DAG and pass certain parameters to the Python callable.

My code looks like below.

```
def my_sleeping_function(threshold):
   print(threshold)

fmfdependency = PythonOperator(
   task_id='poke_check',
   python_callable=my_sleeping_function,
   provide_context=True,
   op_kwargs={'threshold': 100},
   dag=dag)

end = BatchEndOperator(
   queue=QUEUE,
   dag=dag)

start.set_downstream(fmfdependency)
fmfdependency.set_downstream(end)
```

But I keep getting the below error.

> TypeError: my_sleeping_function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dag_run'

Not able to figure out why.

Comment: Please format your code into correct form. It's hard to understand where `my_sleeping_function` returns. What is `PythonOperator`?

Comment: *Apparently* related previous [QA-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54701639/3679900)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add **kwargs to your operator parameters list after your threshold param

Comment: You mean like `op_kwargs={'threshold': 100, **kwargs}`? I have no `kwargs` var to expand like that.

Comment: Even if you don’t have args that you created for the function, The PythonOperator will append a set of parameters to your function call. These operators include some Airflow objects like context, etc.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking it went in my dag's PythonOperator, but it goes in the callable. In this case, `my_sleeping_function(threshold, **kwargs)`.

Comment: This is correct.      I did not see you were asking about putting the kwargs in the PythonOperator constructor.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can pass arguments for a Python operator in Airflow.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

def my_func(*op_args):
        print(op_args)
        return op_args[0]

with DAG('python_dag', description='Python DAG', schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *', start_date=datetime(2018, 11, 1), catchup=False) as dag:
        dummy_task      = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task', retries=3)
        python_task     = PythonOperator(task_id='python_task', python_callable=my_func, op_args=['one', 'two', 'three'])

        dummy_task >> python_task
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question now, with a few solutions. None of them say *why* you're getting the error though.

It's because of `provide_context=True`. It passes an addition set of keyword arguments to the function. A list of what it passes can be found here:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html#templates-variables

As you can see, `dag_run` is there. You can either set `provide_context=False` or add `**kwargs` to your function to handle them.
Hopefully this helps anyone else who stumbles on this question.